# MySQL Counting the number of occurrences of a value from a column in another column and storing in new column

Tags: mysql

How do I structure my query so I can count how many occurrences of a value in column 1 appears in column 2 and then store that result in a new column in the same table? (If a value is duplicated in the first column I still want to store the same value in the new column) For example if I had a table like this:

```
COL1    COL2
1        2
1        4
2        1
3        1
4        1
4        2
```

The resulting table will look like this:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
1        2       3
1        4       3
2        1       2
3        1       0
4        1       1
4        2       1
```

Any help is appreciated I am new to sql! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot follow how the logic you describe in any way matches the results you present.

Comment: @GordonLinoff in the above ex, value 1 in column 1 appears 3 times in column 2 so there for column3 will store the number 3 in relation to the value 1 in column 1...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The information that 1 occurs three times in col2 is already there (you can easily count it). So why store it redundantly in all col1=1 records in the table? This is prone to future errors (when suddenly there are two col1=1 records with different counts or when a col1=1 record has a count that doesn't match the real count). My advice: Don't do this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my apologies that was a typo on my part. Now it should make sense I am sorry about the confusion!!!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes I completely understand where you are coming from, I am doing this because I am working with a vast amount of records in the database(over a million) and a query that I use every time counts the amount of occurrences of a value in col1 in col2. Since there are so many rows in the db it takes far too long for this number to be calculated every time so I want to make a new column which will calculate it once and store it, then I can change my query so I just retrieve the already calculated result for that value.

Comment: Hm, that shouldn't take too long if the column is indexed. If you really  need to store this information for fast access, I'd recommend to have a table with unique col1 along with their according count. Then introduce a trigger to update this table everytime a record in the table shown gets inserted, deleted or updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 
 col1,
 col2,
 COALESCE(col3,0) as col3
FROM 
 mytable 
LEFT JOIN 
( Select count(*) as col3, col2
    from mytable 
   GROUP BY col2) as temp ON temp.col2 = mytable.col1
```

And if you want the update (thanks Thorsten Kettner ) :

```
UPDATE mytable 
LEFT JOIN ( Select count(*) as col3, col2
    from mytable 
   GROUP BY col2) as temp ON temp.col2 = mytable.col1
SET mytable.col3 =  COALESCE(temp.col3,0)
```

Comment: Add COALESCE to show 0 instead of NULL for non-occurring values. This is a good way of selecting the data, but doesn't really answer the question how to fill a new column with the counts. And anyway: an answer should provide more than a mere query.

Comment: Yes i put a +1 on your answer. I was doing some work during my answer ;) Do you know if your select is better than mine for the performance ?

Comment: No, I don't know. If I had to guess, I would think yours might be a tad faster.

Comment: For the update, i almost certain mine is faster because you join on every line as mine do only 1 join.

Comment: Well, the two queries do the same thing, they are just differerently written. A good optimizer should see through this and find about the same execution plan for both queries. But as mentioned in my answer: I wouldn't store these count values anyway. And if I did, I'd not do this in this table.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily count on-the-fly. Don't store this redundantly. This would only cause problems later.

```
select 
  col1, 
  col2,
  (
    select count(*)
    from mytable match
    where match.col2 = mytable.col1
  ) as col3
from mytable;
```

If you think you *must* do it; here is the according UPDATE statement:

```
update mytable 
set col3 =
(
  select count(*)
  from mytable match
  where match.col2 = mytable.col1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you can try :

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, (SELECT COUNT(COL1) FROM `tablename` AS t2 
WHERE t2.COL1 = t1.COL1) AS COL3 FROM `tablename` AS t1
```

Enjoy :)